# how to peridically start Intent service

Tags: android

I need to keep service running to monitor changes through content observer.

I also need to know , Can my alarms set for periodic intervals can be erased ?
If yes then When ?

Can task killers erase Alarms for version onwards 2.2 ?

Comment: I know the answer.. but I'm not Commonsware :(

Comment: dymmeh: :) This question is open for All experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep a service running, use `Service.startForeground`. Then the Android system won't kill it, except under the most extreme circumstances.

You need to supply a notification which is continuously shown to the user so that they know they have a service running which is potentially using resources. This seems to be a deliberate (and sensible) design decision.

So long as you do that, and so long as your `ContentObserver` actually works, there should be no need at all for you to wake up your activity or service code using `AlarmManager`. Your service should just continuously run and your code should be called whenever the content changes.

Comment: Thanks For the Suggestions "Adrian Taylor". Actually I am working on app that sync contacts with personal server through JSON webservices.  I manually first insert all data to sqlite database. then I upload all contacts one by one to server. Now I have the challenge, How to identify that particular rawcontact has been changed? .  And The approach I am using for syncing is the correct one?

Comment: Hi, I don't know the answer to that, sorry. However I expect you're better off using Android's built-in frameworks for synchronizing contacts - see the mentions of sync here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: Specifically that article suggests looking in the SDK samples at 'SampleSyncAdapter' which may help you.

Comment: Sync adapter takes alot of research.. I have been messing around this for 15 days. Hope you can help me !